# LGSideMenuController Version 2 to 3 Update: Deprecated Methods

Tags: ios, swift

Background: complete Swift/iOS development noob.

Trying to update an existing iOS project to latest minimum supported versions and I am encountering the `"Method does not override any method from its superclass"` error for both the `leftViewWillLayoutSubviews` and `rootViewWillLayoutSubviews` methods.

Note: the project I am updated `LGSideMenuController` pod update from version 2.1.1 to 3.1.2.

```
import UIKit
import LGSideMenuController

class SideMenuController: LGSideMenuController {

    \\ other code

    override func leftViewWillLayoutSubviews(with size: CGSize) {
        super.leftViewWillLayoutSubviews(with: size)
        leftView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
    
    override func rootViewWillLayoutSubviews(with size: CGSize) {
        super.rootViewWillLayoutSubviews(with: size)
        rootView?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    }
}
```

Is `leftViewLayoutSubviews` the updated method of `leftViewWillLayoutSubviews` and `rootViewLayoutSubviews` the updated method of `rootViewWillLayoutSubviews`?

If so, how would I be able to obtain `size` value to set `frame`?